# Exception: FlutterError (Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/testResult()", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, timer

I'm adding a timer for my Flutter quiz app. But when the timer ends, the following exception occurs:

FlutterError (Could not find a generator for route
RouteSettings("/ResultBox()", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:

1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
   Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.)

Code:

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var db = DBconnect();
  late Future _questions;
  Future<List<Question>> getData() async {
    return db.fetchQuestions();
  }

  late AnimationController _controller;

  final limitTime = 10;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    if (_controller.isAnimating || _controller.isCompleted)
      _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _questions = getData();
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: limitTime));
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.isCompleted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/testResult");
      }
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To have a route known by MaterialApp router, you need to declare the route in MaterialApp call:

```
MaterialApp(
          ...
          routes: {
            '/home': (_) => const HomeView(),
            '/about': (_) => const AboutView(),
            '/testResult': (_) => const youtTestResultView(),
          },
          ...
);
```